# PostgreSQL Text column to integer column

Tags: postgresql

I have to convert one text column to integer column.
Showed code work when I have text (all numbers) in fields but now I find some empty strings '' where query stops.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE integer USING (TRIM(mycolumn)::integer);
```

Can here be done so that empty strings be converted to integer 0 so this query will pass?
How to do this?

Comment: concate your field with a '0'. something like `(Trim('0'|mycolumns)::integer)`

Comment: This works excellent, thank you very much! (Trim('0'||mycolumns))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your values before altering table:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = '0' WHERE mycolumn = '';
```